# jquery check all checkboxes and add class to rows?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, addclass, toggleclass

I am trying to add a class to my tr rows if the select all checkbox has been selected, but I can't seem to get the add class to work (and then obviously remove them if check all has been deselected), I am using toggle on each individual row to add/remove the class, but can't seem to get it working for the check all.

Here's my table:

```
<form>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="tablesorter" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" name="checkall"></th>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="header filename"><strong>Filename</strong></th>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="header filesize"><strong>Size</strong></th>
      <th valign="middle" align="left" class="header filedate"><strong>Date</strong></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="file">
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">Search48.png</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">6 KB</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">21/10/2010</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filebox"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" name="checkbox"></td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filename">shopping_trolley48.png</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filesize">3 KB</td>
      <td valign="middle" align="left" class="filedate">21/10/2010</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Here's my jquery code:

```
//check all checkboxes
$("#checkall").click(function () {
  $(this).parents("#table:eq(0)").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked);
});

//add highlight to tr
$("#checkbox").click(function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant use an ID here since it's repeated, instead use a class like `class="checkbox"` instead of the `id="checkbox"`, like this:

```
$("#checkall").change(function () {
  $(this).closest("table").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked).change();
});

$(".checkbox").change(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/H3tMf/).  Also note the use of [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) so the state is correct, the use of [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the nearest parent of that selector, and calling [`.change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) on all the checkboxes you're changing, so their row class gets updated correctly.

Comment: thank you, but it's not adding the new classes for the rows on check all

Comment: @Soulie - did you add the `.change()` on the second line in my code above? :) Check the demo to see it working.

Comment: $("#checkall").change(function () {
    $(this).closest("table").find(":checkbox").attr("checked", this.checked).change();
  });
  $(".check").change(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("highlight", this.checked);
  });

Comment: oh wait, i didnt change 1 class name.. ugh now it works! Thank you so much for your help!! :)

Answer (score 1):

http://beckelman.net/2008/11/18/select-all-checkboxes-in-a-table-column-with-and-without-jquery-plugin-demo/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tableOne thead tr th:first input:checkbox").click(function() {
        var checkedStatus = this.checked;
        $("#tableOne tbody tr td:first-child input:checkbox").each(function() {
            this.checked = checkedStatus;
        });
    });

});
</script>
```